# Is it possible to set the SourceItem of a combobox with a DataTrigger?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have three collections in my view model, one for items of category 1, others for items of category 2 and other for items for category 3.

Also, I have another property that is IDCategory with the category of the view model.

I have a comboBox in my view that I want to bind to the first collection if the property IDCategory of the view model is 1, that binds the second collection if the property IDCategory is 2 to binds the last collection if the IDCategory is 3.

I am trying to use a datatrigger in this way:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=DataContext.IDCategory}" Value="1">
                                                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding MyCollection1}"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=DataContext.IDCategory}" Value="2">
                                                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding MyCollection2}"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=DataContext.IDCategory}" Value="3">
                                                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding MyCollection3}"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

But ItemsSource isn't available in the set of the dataTrigger, so I am wondering if really it is possible this kind of solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Triggers should be in a ComboBox Style:

```
<ComboBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=DataContext.IDCategory}"
                         Value="1">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding MyCollection1}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=DataContext.IDCategory}"
                         Value="2">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding MyCollection2}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=DataContext.IDCategory}"
                         Value="3">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding MyCollection3}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Style>
```